# A multiple choice question on algebra

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that for every two arbitrary subgroup $H$ and $K$ of $G$, $H\subseteq K$ or $K\subseteq H$. Which of the following statements is true?

(a) $G$ need not to be cyclic.

(b) $G$ is the product of two cyclic group.

(c) $G$ has only two subgroups.

(d) $G$ is cyclic and the order of $G$ is a power of $p$ for some prime number $p$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Which is true, and why are the other ones not? We'll happily confirm or correct.

Comment: I'm sure you know enough small examples of groups to rule out several of these alternatives. Why not try some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is cyclic.

Proof: Lets assume that $G$ is not cyclic. Thus, we have an element $a\in G$ with $<a>\neq G$ and an element $b\in G-<a>$. Then we get $<a>\subsetneq<b>$. Therefore $G$ ist cyclic, because $G$ is finit.

$G$ is the product of two cyclic groups.

Proof: $G$ is isomorphic to $G\times\{1\}$ the product of two cyclic groups.

It is possible that $G$ has more than two subgroups.

Example: $Z/4Z$ has the subgroups $\{0\}\subset<2>\subset Z/4Z$.

G is cyclic (already proven) and the order of $G$ is a power of $p$ for some prime number $p$.

Proof: Lets assume that $a,b$ are distinct prime factors of the order of $G$. Take an element $x\in G$ with $<x>=G$. The subgroups $H:=<x^{\mathrm{ord}G/a}>$ and $K:=<x^{\mathrm{ord}G/b}>$ have order $a$ and $b$ respectively. Thus we have $K\not\subseteq H$ and $H\not\subseteq K$.